# How to set up a socket using raw sockettype

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, socketexception

I am trying to set up a socket communication using ScketType.Raw (it is necessary for the device I'm communicating with that I send my own header and checksum).  I am new to socket connections and extremely new to Raw socket types, and am having trouble setting it up.

The code and IP address/port combination I have works fine for SocketType.Stream, but fails using SocketType.Raw.  What other information is required to set up a socket connection using SocketType.Raw?

```
string txtPort = tbPort.Text;
string txtIP = tbIPAddress.Text;
int port = System.Convert.ToInt16(txtPort);
ip = IPAddress.Parse(txtIP);
ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);

// this works but doesn't suit my needs
//MainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
//MainSocket.Connect(ipEnd);

// This fails: An invalid argument was supplied (ip address and port of the device I am connecting to)
MainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Tcp);
MainSocket.Connect(ipEnd);
```

Comment: the commented out code that you say works is the same as the uncommented code that you say fails, copy paste error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to create a raw socket that uses the TCP protocol number; ie, you are trying to provide your own implementation of TCP.

You cannot create raw sockets that use the TCP protocol; management and correct implementation of the TCP protocol requires holistic support from the operating system, support which you will be unable to provide in your implementation of TCP.

You can still create raw sockets for UDP or for IP itself; in the case of IP itself, you cannot transmit packets from your raw socket that have the protocol number set to TCP.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> #### Limitations on Raw Sockets
>
> On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3), the ability to send traffic over raw sockets has been restricted in several ways:
>
> - TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.

Comment: I completely agree, RIP

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, does ProtocolType.IPv4 work? eg

```
MainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IPv4);
```

Comment: honestly not really sure. Tcp might have been trying to create an IPv6 socket by default

Comment: A random answer is never good for upvoting, even if accidentally got results which seem to work.

Comment: The reason why it works is because you can't create a raw TCP socket - if the socket is raw, you will have to implement tcp yourself.

Comment: Right, but even if it didnt say why, it still shows that you cant create a raw tcp socket... so still a good answer.